# NPM package sharing

Tags: reactjs, npm, azure-devops, devops

I am currently using Azure DevOps for the CI / CD of my React component on the npmjs platform. I am currently developing an extended version of my basic application package. How do I share my npm package with my clients? I want to be able to grant permission to use versions to groups / individual programmers in the easiest way. Any solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: use `.npmrc` to do that

Comment: In devops, feed in artifacts is the most recommended way to share npm/nuget/python packages. So on server side, you group the users and give the group permission to access one feed, and one client side, the users configure the .npmrc and their PAT and install the package from cloud feed.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I share my npm package with my clients? I want to be able to
>   grant permission to use versions to groups / individual programmers in
>   the easiest way. Any solutions?

Assuming you already have a feed to host the npm package, if not, [create one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-npm?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#create-a-feed) and [publish your package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-npm?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#publish-an-npm-package) to this feed.

1.You can create a custom `UserGroup` in `Project Settings => Permissions`, use this group to group those users you want to grant permission to.

2.Go `Artifacts => Feed => Feed settings` to set the permission, add the `UserGroup`/`individual programmers` to the list. It depends on you that which role permission they can be granted, about feed permissions check [this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#feed-permissions-overview).

[image]

3.Now the users in that group or the individual programmers you add to the list can access the package within the npm feed. So that can follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) to set up their .npmrc file, after that they can easily fetch the package from private npm feed using `npm install` command.

Note: If you want to limit the UserGroup/individual programmers' permissions (Only give them permission to read the npm package? ). You can consider customizing the related settings in [Project Settings=>Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page%2Ccurrent-page#inheritance-and-security-groups) and [repos settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops#set-git-repository-permissions).